# Submitting form data without submit button not working

Tags: html, dom

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function submit() {
        document.getElementById("myform").submit();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myform" method="post" action="index.php">
        <h1> AWB_NO</h1>
        <input type=text name="excel" onchange="submit()" >
        </br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to JavaScript and PHP! I am trying to submit the form data without the submit button.The Event listener works fine and loads the PHP page but it doesn't execute the script, as it would with the submit button. I do not want to use the submit button!

Comment: `getElementById` uses for id. So use `id="myform"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are using the name instead of id.

Change this line

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="index.php">
```

to

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="index.php">
```

Comment: You haven't written anything.

Comment: Refresh the page please. I don't know why it is not showing when I added the respond.

Comment: @PramodS Change the `name` attribute to `id` since in your code you use `getElementById` and not `getElementsByName`.

Comment: I think it is getElementsByName instead of getElementByName

Comment: @NeilVillareal Yea ur right. Sry for typo, corrected :D

Comment: Note: It will return an array of elements with that name so I think it is better to follow what I suggested above.

Comment: will this work if i want to send the form data to the same page,and keep the php script on the same page.

Comment: what will be the value of this "if(isset($_POST['submit']))" ? or should i use something else?

Comment: you can add a hidden field with a name submit and have a value submitted

Comment: Example: <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submitted" />

Comment: this code "if(isset($_POST['submit']))" will just work fine with this field <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submitted" /> added inside your form.

Comment: When i add the hidden file type i have to press enter to submit the data. I want to be able to submit it without having to do that. It should submit when the text field changes.

Comment: No, What i think actually happend is that the onchange event is triggered when you press the enter key or remove the focus on the field.

Comment: Yes,onchange is triggered when you remove focus,but hidden input does not do that. I have to press the enter button when i use hidden input